# 17" mid-2009 MBP, 3.06 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo: can it take 16GB RAM?

Tags: macbook-pro, memory, unibody

Does anyone have this unibody from mid-2009? Has anyone upgraded it to 16GB RAM? If so, is it good news?

Thanks!

Comment: @thinkr ignoring for the moment that closing seven year old questions which have answers is rarely necessary: Why do you consider this to lead to opinion-based answers?

Answer (score 6):

If you mean either the '[SD](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-2-duo-3.06-aluminum-15-mid-2009-sd-unibody-specs.html)' or the '[Mid 2009](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-2-duo-3.06-aluminum-17-mid-2009-unibody-specs.html)' then no, it can take 8GB only.

[EveryMac](http://www.everymac.com) is a fabulous resource for that type of info, including in some cases, whether a machine can actually take more RAM than the Apple official original spec claims.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have this MacBook Pro anymore as I sold it but I do know that it can't take 16GB of RAM, only up to 8GB.